# Owin startup not called when using web api 2 in process with HttpServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, owin, httpserver

I'm trying to use HttpServer to host my Web API 2 site in-process. It is mostly working - I can get/post methods etc. (See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2013/01/28/writing-tests-for-an-asp-net-web-api-service/, "Submitting requests against an in-memory HttpServer", for example). The issue is that the OwinStartup method is never being called and so the OwinContext is null and so I can not get reference to things like the ApplicationUserManager. My understanding is that using HttpServer is essentially identical to hosting the web api in IIS or similar, and so the owin startup method should be called. Here is a code sample:

Client:

```
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = 
        RouteParameter.Optional });
    using(var server = new HttpServer(config))        
    using(var client = new HttpMessageInvoker(server))
    {
        var address = "http://localhost/account/register";
        var r = new RegisterBindingModel() { Email = "abc@abc.com", Password="abc!123", ConfirmPassword = "abc!123" };
        using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address))
        {
            request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r), Encoding.Default, "application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None).Result)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Startup:

```
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Test.Startup))]
    namespace Test
    {
        public partial class Startup
        {
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                 //Not called.. (is called when hosting in IIS)
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
         var userManager = UserManager; //This is null.
         return Ok();
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {         
            //Request.GetOwinContext() is null.       
            return _userManager ??Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Is there something I am missing? How do I get the Startup method to be called?

Comment: That's not going to work, that HttpMessageInvoker is bypassing anything that might include OWIN.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That's pretty much what I concluded. I'm not really sure what's the point of this technique, then, but anyway.

Comment: It's good for unit testing portions of your app in memory. Tests are much more reliable when your can cut out the network.